# Adding comment to post in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, action

EDIT: I am trying to add a comment to a post in my mvc application but my action does not seem to work. When I reach the Action I want to pass on an Id from a Post (the Id from the table/model FormalBlog) but the newPost.Post = model.Post is null and when the action reaches the db.SaveChanges it throws an System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException.

Below is my action and my PostIndexViewModel:

```
     public ActionResult Comment(PostIndexViewModel model, FormalBlog Post)
    {
        var userName = User.Identity.Name;
        var author = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName);

        Comment newPost = new Comment();

        newPost.Author = author;
        newPost.Text = model.Text;
        newPost.Post = model.Post;


        db.Comments.Add(newPost);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("ShowBlogs", "Blog");

    }
}

public class PostIndexViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FormalBlog> FormalBlogs { get; set; }
    public FormalBlog NewFormalBlog { get; set; } = new FormalBlog();
    public Category NewCategory { get; set; } = new Category();
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> SelectedCategories { get; set; }
    public int[] CategoryIds { get; set; }
    public Category CategoryN { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; } //testrad

   // public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }
    public Comment NewComment { get; set; }
    public FormalBlog Post { get; set; }

}
```

and here is the code for my view:

```
@model XP_Scrum_Grupp2.Controllers.PostIndexViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Comment", "Blog", new { formal = Model }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = Model.Id }))
{

    <div class="comment-form-container">
        <form class="comment-form" data-action="@Url.Action("Comment", "Blog")">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)

            <div>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Author)</div>
            <div>
                <div>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Text)</div>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Text, new { Class = "comment-text", rows = "3", cols = "50" })
            </div>
            <div class="comment-result" style="display: none;">
                <span class="comment-result-text">An error occurred</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="comment-form-submit">Submit comment</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view does not assign any value to `model.NewComment`. So when you access `model.NewComment.Text` it will throw Null reference exception since `model.NewComment` is null.

You assign new text to model's Test property. So you should use `model.Text` instead of `model.NewComment.Text`

```
public ActionResult Comment(PostIndexViewModel model)
    {
        var userName = User.Identity.Name;
        var author = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == userName);

        Comment newPost = new Comment();

        newPost.Author = author;
        newPost.Text = model.Text;
        newPost.Post = model.Post;


        db.Comments.Add(newPost);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("ShowBlogs", "Blog");

    }
```

Comment: Thanks it really improved my code but now I have another issue..When I try to save the new comment it throws an System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException when reaching db.SaveChanges(); and I think my newPost.Post is null . Do you see how I might fix that?

Comment: Good to hear that my solution help to solve your issue. If your issue solved please mark it as the correct answer. If not please update your question, so we can help you.

Comment: Your view does not assign a value to Post property. What I understand is you are trying to add a comment to existing post. So you should get post Id with PostIndexViewModel model. So you can query your post from backend and assign it to newPost.Post

Comment: newPost.Post = db.Posts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == model.PostId);

Comment: Yes you understand exactly what I want to achieve but I am such a newbie to this and I cant seem to retrieve the postID. I get the error " Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'ApplicationUser' and 'FormalBlog' XP_Scrum_Grupp2 "  when writing
 newPost.Post = db.FormalBlogs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Author == model.PostId);

Comment: What you refer to as 'Post' is my FormalBlog I assume because it is in that model/table that I am posting things

Comment: Currently, your PostIndexViewModel model doesn't have a property for PostId. So first you have defined a property for PostId. Then you can assign your blog post Id to that property.

Comment: what is the relation between FormalBlog and Post?

Comment: It is a one-to-many public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

Comment: Your action receiving "FormalBlog Post". Is it not the correct post to assign newPost.Post ?

Comment: yes it is. But I don't know if it should be there or not.. Im thinking that the action have to get an Postid into the action to be able to assign the comment to just that specific  post.

Comment: How you populate PostIndexViewModel to pass to your view (Form). I think at that time you can assign PostIndexViewModel.Post property.

Comment: Thanks man for the help but I think I am going to post a new question later if I don't solve this any time soon. But I am gonna mark the question as Solved here because you helped me with the original issue :) Thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

You are not posting the any data as `model.NewComment.Text` so the error occures because of `NewComment` object is `null`.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Text, new { Class = "comment-text", rows = "3", cols = "50" })
```

So, try to change it;

```
newPost.Text = model.NewComment.Text;
```

to

```
newPost.Text = model.Text;
```